# Are Legendary Crafting Materials able to drop from Rifts or other areas?

Tags: diablo-iii

Are specific Legendary Crafting Materials restricted to only the super-unique bosses that are described in the material list, or can these same materials also drop from places like...rifts, and other areas.

A good example.  If I am looking to farm "Demon Skin" materials... the site says they only drop from 4 specific Super-Unique bosses.  Is it possible to farm them inside Rifts instead, or do they have no drop chance out side of those super-unique bosses.

Comment: http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/83094-guide-legendary-crafting-materials-drop-locations  Hopefully this link helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Legendary crafting materials will only drop from the specific purple super-uniques.  They will not drop from any other monster.  Since none of the purple super-uniques ever show up in rifts, you cannot get them anywhere else.

The only legendary crafting mats that can drop in rifts are the ones not tied to super uniques, such as the Adventurer's Journal.